# Loading content into div from tabs

Tags: javascript, php, variables, tabs

I am trying to use a php variable that holds an html snippet to display inside a div when an `<li>` is clicked. The below code works if the variable only holds a string of text with no html. But as soon as I add html it stops working. What am I doing wrong?

I have updated the code based on help I received below, but it is still not working.

This works:

```
$(function() {
            $('#tab-1').click(function() {
                    alert('click event called!'); var tabcontent = "Test Content";
                    document.getElementById('top-tabs-content').innerHTML = tabcontent;
            });
            });
```

This doesn't:

```
$(function() {
            $('#tab-1').click(function() {
                    alert('click event called!'); var tabcontent = "<?php echo json_encode($tabcontent[0]);?>";
                    document.getElementById('top-tabs-content').innerHTML = tabcontent;
            });
            });
```

Comment: What does it say when you log the variable with `console.log(tabcontent)`?

Comment: So I've determined that if I take out the "echo" part of the function so it reads `alert('click event called!'); var tabcontent = "<?php json_encode($tabcontent[0]);?>";` the function will work but no content displays (obviously). What could be going wrong with the echo? Is there a different way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
var tabcontent = "<?php echo $tabcontent[1]; ?>"
```

with

```
var tabcontent = "'" + "<?php echo $tabcontent[1]; ?>" + "'";
```

Comment: yes, if you want to be secure
`var tabcontent = "'" + "<?php echo htmlentities($tabcontent[1],ENT_QUOTES);?>" + "'";`

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's still not quite working. I've updated the question with what I currently have.

Comment: OK, I added the whole snippet with html context. I am getting the php variable from an array. I am echoing that variable fine above the script, so I know it's returning some sort of value.

Comment: I have tested your JS code, there is nothing wrong with it. there might be something else that is not letting it run...
make sure you dont have any errors in your javascript and jquery onclick function is being called(try to use `alert(tabcontent);` in onclick funtion. and also make sure that you are getting something from php variable.

Comment: I'm definitely getting something from the php variable as I'm displaying it as the default text of the first tab successfully. I'm not well-versed in javascript so troubleshooting this type of thing is a little beyond me.... I'll keep trying to figure it out.

Comment: `$(function() {
    $('#tab-1').click(function() {
alert('click event called!');
        var tabcontent = "'" + "<?php echo htmlentities($tabcontent[0],ENT_QUOTES);?>" + "'";
alert(tabcontent);
        document.getElementById('top-tabs-content').innerHTML = tabcontent;

    });
    });`

Comment: try to replace above code with your for `id=tab-1`, Click on **li with `id=tab-1`** and see the alert messages that you get.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It works if only put text into the variable but not if the html snippet is in it. This works `$(function() {
  $('#tab-1').click(function() {
   alert('click event called!'); var tabcontent = "test content";
   document.getElementById('top-tabs-content').innerHTML = tabcontent;
  });
  });` . This does not: `$(function() {
  $('#tab-1').click(function() {
   alert('click event called!'); var tabcontent = "'" + "<?php echo htmlentities($tabcontent[0],ENT_QUOTES);?>" + "'";
   document.getElementById('top-tabs-content').innerHTML = tabcontent;
  });
  });`

Comment: try without `htmlentities` function

Comment: Tried this with no luck: `$(function() {
  $('#tab-1').click(function() {
   alert('click event called!'); var tabcontent = "'" + "<?php echo $tabcontent[0];?>" + "'";
   document.getElementById('top-tabs-content').innerHTML = tabcontent;
  });
  });`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45023/discussion-between-muhammad-saud-and-eckstein)

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!
preg_replace and addslashes works to make the javascript correct. The issue was that the html inside the variable was multiple lines, which doesn't work in a JS function. Here is the way to set a JS var to a PHP var without it breaking:

```
var tabcontent = "<?php echo preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", addslashes($tabcontent[1]));?>";
```